# python inserting schema url in xtree tag names

Tags: xml, python-3.x, elementtree

I am a newbie to Python with some Perl experience. My script is parsing some public XML files that are "sitemaps" to collections of content, for instance https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_11.70.0/sitemap.xml.gz

When I use the .tag function to get the tag names, it returns a whole string with the 'sitemap' schema in it. For example:

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
root = ET.fromstring(content)
for child in root:
    print(child.tag)
```

results in:

```
{http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9}sitemap
```

when all I want is:

```
sitemap
```

In order to search on those tags/paths I need to include that whole {} string, or else it won't find them.

Perhaps it's something to do with my `html.client` call?

```py
conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection("www.ibm.com")
conn.request("GET", url)
r1 = conn.getresponse()
content = r1.read()
```

I didn't see anything in the online doc - am I missing something? Thanks.

Comment: That url is actually a namespace uri. Take a look at https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#parsing-xml-with-namespaces for more info on parsing XML with namespaces in ElementTree.

Comment: Also, check out http://www.jclark.com/xml/xmlns.htm for more information on namespaces in general.

Comment: Great, thank you! very helpful.